# BufferUnderflowException during finding implementations in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse, whenever I'm trying to open the implementation of an abstract method by hovering over the method name while pressing ctrl, it's giving me this error. 
Please have a look at the pic attached.
I've searched some documents and none of them were actually related to my issue.

Thanks in Advance.

[Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM9ej.png)

Error Stack

```
!STACK 0
java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
    at java.nio.CharBuffer.get(CharBuffer.java:688)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.db.Chunk.getChars(Chunk.java:325)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.db.LongString.getChars(LongString.java:116)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.NdMethodId.getSelector(NdMethodId.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.NdMethodId.isConstructor(NdMethodId.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.model.IndexBinaryType.createBinaryMethod(IndexBinaryType.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.nd.java.model.IndexBinaryType.getMethods(IndexBinaryType.java:275)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFileInfo.generateMethodInfos(ClassFileInfo.java:254)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFileInfo.readBinaryChildren(ClassFileInfo.java:427)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ClassFile.buildStructure(ClassFile.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.Openable.generateInfos(Openable.java:259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SourceRefElement.generateInfos(SourceRefElement.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.openWhenClosed(JavaElement.java:579)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.BinaryType.getElementInfo(BinaryType.java:287)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaElement.getElementInfo(JavaElement.java:302)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.find(SearchableEnvironment.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.SearchableEnvironment.findType(SearchableEnvironment.java:294)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CancelableNameEnvironment.findType(CancelableNameEnvironment.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:212)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.superInterfaces(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1941)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.superInterfaces(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1957)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.getExactMethod(BinaryTypeBinding.java:1148)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.findExactMethod(Scope.java:1259)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getMethod(Scope.java:2864)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.findMethodBinding(MessageSend.java:934)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MessageSend.resolveType(MessageSend.java:757)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.Expression.resolve(Expression.java:1026)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:634)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.MethodDeclaration.resolveStatements(MethodDeclaration.java:306)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.AbstractMethodDeclaration.resolve(AbstractMethodDeclaration.java:544)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1195)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1308)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1030)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.resolve(Compiler.java:1075)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnitProblemFinder.process(CompilationUnitProblemFinder.java:271)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.makeConsistent(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.executeOperation(ReconcileWorkingCopyOperation.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.run(JavaModelOperation.java:724)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.JavaModelOperation.runOperation(JavaModelOperation.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1250)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.core.CompilationUnit.reconcile(CompilationUnit.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.access$0(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy$1.run(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.java.JavaReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaReconcilingStrategy.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.CompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(CompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.text.JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.reconcile(JavaCompositeReconcilingStrategy.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.MonoReconciler.process(MonoReconciler.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jface.text.reconciler.AbstractReconciler$BackgroundThread.run(AbstractReconciler.java:207)
```

Comment: Look in the .log file in the workspace .metadata directory to see if there is a more detailed message.

Comment: Updated the question with error stack. Please check.